# MutiText Input using JFACE with the help of + button

Tags: text, input, jface

I am new to JFACE and was designing a multitext input in the following way.

composite.setLayout(layout);
        composite.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));

```
    Label text1=new Label(composite,SWT.NONE);
    text1.setText("Provide The names");
    text1.setForeground(darkmagenta);
    text1.setFont(boldFont);
    noOfTables= new Text(composite, SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER | SWT.WRAP | SWT.V_SCROLL );

    noOfTables.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));
```

and it is working fine.

However I wanted to know if I could add a muli user input using a + button.
Say a user inputs a name , then if he has one more name to add , he clicks on the + button and another text area opens for him below.

I have looked online for this and didn't come up with anything

Any help/comments would be welcome.

Cheers,

P

Answer (score 0):

It's not hard ... just put a selection listener on your button that invokes a method that creates a new Composite inside your parent Composite and pack the outermost container (Shell) after the new container is added.

Your button listener would look something like this:

```
public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
    displays.add(createArea(c));
    shell.pack();
}
```

The createArea method would look something like this:

```
private Composite createArea(Composite c) {

    Composite inner = new Composite(c, SWT.NONE);
    inner.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
    inner.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.END, true, false));

    GridData gd = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true,true);

    Label l = new Label(inner, SWT.NONE);
    l.setText("Label #" + lCount++);
    l.setLayoutData(gd);

    Text t = new Text(inner, SWT.NONE);
    t.setLayoutData(gd);
    return inner;
}
```

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for the help. However when I add the displays.add(createArea(c)); in my button listener , it cannot resolve displays.add .I am new to this so don't mind me asking is the add an inbuilt function ? Any input would be welcom

Comment: The displays variable is just a List object that I accumulate created composites to.  In hind sight, it might be better to have the createArea return the Text you are creating instead of the Composite. Take a look at http://code.midrange.com/3e819ab196.html for an example.